# Is there a significant difference between closures and the visitor pattern?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, groovy, closures

I've been recently playing with Groovy and have messed around with JRuby before and appreciate using the `.each{}` closure in their collections.

That said, I cannot help but feel that this is nothing but syntactic sugar for a visitor pattern. If you encapsulated the code within the body of the closure within a class and passed an instance of that class using the visitor pattern it seems like the exact same thing, albeit with less hassle.

So, are there other capabilities of closures that I haven't yet seen that make them fundamentally different that the visitor pattern, or are people just really that excited over this syntactic sugar?

To me it seems like more of a library issue than a language issue.

---

Here is a quick mock-up a Java list that seems to behave like the `each` closure in Groovy lists.

```
public class ClosureList<E> extends ArrayList<E>{

    interface Visitor<E>{
            void visit( E e );
    }

    void accept( Visitor<E> v ){
        for( Iterator<E> myItr = this.iterator(); myItr.hasNext() )
            v.visit( myItr.next() );
    }

}
```

Then just have

```
public class ClosureTest{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        ClosureList<String> myList = new ClosureList<String>();
        myList.add( "green eggs" );
        myList.add( "green ham"  );


        clStr.accept(
                new Visitor<String>(){
                    void visit( String s ){
                        System.out.println( s )
                    }
                }
            );
    }
}
```

which seems the same to in Groovy:

```
def l = [ "green eggs", "green ham" ]
l.each{ println it }
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample in any language? Visitor is used to avoid downcasting and `instanceof` - how are closures (actually, you probably mean code blocks and higher order functions) helping with that?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz There you go, a visitor pattern that seems to emulate closures *almost* as concisely as Groovy would.

Comment: IMHO, The biggest difference is that closures are more concise. There are other quirks which make closure more natural.

Comment: Aren't you arguing that `each` in groovy is like a concise implementation of the visitor pattern? There's more to closures than `each`

Comment: @PeterLawrey well most of the bloadt comes from the fact that there is no variadic constructor for arraylist and then 2 extra lines for defining the inner class and it's method.

Comment: @tim_yates no I'm not arguing, I'm asking is there more, because this is all I've seen so far. Please post an answer if you can show me where closures are used differently.

Comment: Check out [builders](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) like [`AntBuilder`](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/groovy-goodness-using-antbuilder.html?m=1), or things like [`File.withReader`](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/groovy-goodness-readers-and-writers.html?m=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your point is to say that the each function is an implementation of the visitor pattern, you are right. Instead of passing an anonymous implementation of an interface, you pass a closure.

A closure is not a visitor. In this case a closure is used to implement a visitor.

Of course, under the hood, a closure is implemented via an inner class, so if your point is to say that closures are nothing magical, most of us will agree.

There are important scoping points to make about the difference between a closure and an anonymous class in java, most notably access to non-final variables, and configurable delegation strategies.

In groovy, you can also instantiate a closure by denoting a kind of reference to an instance method, like this:

```
def c=this.&doSomething
```

This will create a MethodClosure that you will able to use to transport your method, and reduce the granlarity of your modularity from Class to Method.

So we are starting to wander very far away from the visitor pattern, aren't we?

I think that finally in my understanding a closure is an OO way of making methods a first class citizen and reap the benefits of functional style programming.

Comment: Thank you, because from all the hype around I got the impression they were some uber-high-level abstract like continuations that enable a class of things.

Comment: Actually, they do change a lot of things. They really changed my programming style, and I can say that my code is shorter, more modular, and more reusable now. But it's nothing magical.

Comment: Not accurate to say 'each' is an implementation of visitor, visitor can have different processing per visited element sub-type, and can be applied to non-collections. You can simulate visitor with closures if you like. There is more to visitor than 'each' and there's more to closures than visitor and 'each' - as pointed out by others.

Answer (score 3):

The key part that is missing is that the **visited** object needs to have an `accept` method. In the example you describe above, the item in the `each` construct is not guaranteed to have any methods...

`each` constructs are more akin to looping.

I'll also point out that a closure is a scoping construct, and the Visitor Pattern is a design pattern.  So from that point of view, they have absolutely *nothing* to do with each other.

Comment: `I'll also point out that a closure is a scoping construct, and the Visitor Pattern is a design pattern.` True, but it seems that a closure can be simulated with a visitor pattern so well as to not matter.

Comment: Thats like saying you can learn to fly by driving a car.  They have nothing to do with each other.  Closure === what is in a context when.  pattern === how do i write code.